# Connecting sata2 device inside of turned off device

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I would like to connect my laptop which has sata2 connectivity on the case to a PC which does not have any hdd. By doing this I would be able to use the data on laptops hdd on PC without unplugging a disc from laptop. My question is if it is possible, more precisely, if laptop is turned off, can I connect to its hdd using the sata connectivity on the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. This will not work.

SATA is a host/slave type interface and those ports on your laptop are only able to connect to (host) external SATA hard disks (slaves), they will not allow your laptop to "show up" as an external hard disk (i.e. be a slave) to another machine.

You are better off looking into sharing files via a USB drive, Dropbox or similar,  a network share or NAS (Network Attached Storage) solution.